# JQuery animate текущие стили

Tags: jquery, javascript

Доброго времени суток, вопрос не принципиален, просто интересуюсь:

например есть div с id "t". У дива прописан стиль: padding:100px;

Пишу JQuery код:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#t").animate({
        padding : 1000,
    }, 10000)
})
```

По логике(во всяком случае я так считаю) анимация должна начинаться со 100 и закачиваться 1000, но функция сбрасывает padding и анимация начинается с 0. Есть ли в jquery какой либо способ избежать такого поведения?

---

Чтобы, хотя-бы, анимация начиналась с максимальных или минимальных значения padding, margin (left,top,right,bottom) а не с ноля.

---

Или хотя-бы что-то типа

```
  $("#t").animate({
    padding : 1000,
    from: 100
  },
```

---

Не понимаю какой в этом смысл (но дабы удовлетворить человека):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Animation</title>
        <style type="text/css">#t {padding:100px;}</style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#t").animate({
            'padding' : 1000,
        }, 10000)
    })
</script>
    <p id="t" style="padding:100px;">test</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Печально, баг был обнаружен 14 месяцев назад и так ничего и не предпринято...

Вывод: 
так задумано xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего баг jQury http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7399 :
Решение :

```
'padding-top': '+=1000px', 
'padding-left': '+=1000px',
'padding-right': '+=1000px',
'padding-bottom': '+=1000px'
```

Comment: Пробовал, результат тот-же

Comment: попробуйте прописать паддинг непосредственно в теге, может что-то его изменяет?

Comment: У меня на странице крому этого кода нет ничего, ничто его не меняет.

Непосредственно в теге написал - как и ожидал результата это не дало

Comment: покажите код полностью

Comment: Я кагбы умею код писать и кагбы уже написал что кроме этого кода больше ничего нет, тем не менее смотрите =\

Comment: vozmite <p> vo vneshnij konteiner i dayte emu padding 100px;

Comment: Я не спрашивал как сделать костылями. костылями и я могу, я спрашивал именно о нативной поддержке.
****
Ваш последний коммент в ответ переместите.

Comment: Vu pravu. Eto bug na samom dele
http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7399

Reshenie - zadavat 'padding-top': '+=1000px',
     'padding-left': '+=1000px',
     'padding-right': '+=1000px',
     'padding-bottom': '+=1000px',

Comment: @ROOT, В ответ перенесите)